# Fill blank lines in a text file with each line of another file

Tags: bash, awk, while-loop

So basically I have a text file with a lot of blank lines. Let's call it **time.txt** and a part of this file looks like this:

```
       1          5   20    
       2          5   12    
       1          6   3    
       2          6   4

       1          10   30    
       2          10   21    
       1          11   27    
       2          12   8
       1          11   34    
       2          12   20

       1          10   30    
       2          10   21
```

Now, I have another file, called **location.txt**, which contains the same number of lines as the number of blank lines in **time.txt**. It looks like this:

```
   110      -7      5.000              66
   110      -7      5.000              99
   110      -7      5.000              60
```

And what I want is actually simple: I just want to fill the blank lines in **time.txt** with each line in **location.txt**, giving the intended results:

```
   110      -7      5.000              66
       1          5   20    
       2          5   12    
       1          6   3    
       2          6   4
   110      -7      5.000              99
       1          10   30    
       2          10   21    
       1          11   27    
       2          12   8
       1          11   34    
       2          12   20
   110      -7      5.000              60
       1          10   30    
       2          10   21
```

My way to solve this is by reading line by line **location.txt**, store each line in a variable within the loop, and then using awk to detect empty lines inside **time.txt** and replace it with stored loop variable. My code looks like this:

```
time="time.txt"
location="location.txt"
while read -r lines_locs; do
    awk '!NF{$0=$lines_locs}1' $time
done < "$location"
```

but this only prints out **time.txt** in my screen with no replacements made. Plus, I had too many lines printed compared to the expected number of lines. I'm sure that I'm missing something and I would be glad if someone can point this out.

Comment: how many lines are you expecting in each file? also, are the blank lines really blank or do they contain white space (eg, spaces, tabs)?

Comment: 39757 lines in **time.txt** and 643 lines in **location.txt**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One in awk using `getline`:

```
$ awk -v file="$location" 'NF==0{if((getline < file)<=0)$0=""}1' "$time"
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v file="$location" '    # location file as parameter
NF==0 {                        # NF==0 considers bare space records empty
    if((getline < file)<=0)    # when empty read from another file. if failure
        $0=""                  # reset the record. see comments for discussion
}1' "$time"                    # output
```

Output:

```
   110      -7      5.000              66
       1          5   20    
       2          5   12    
       1          6   3    
       2          6   4
   110      -7      5.000              99
       1          10   30    
       2          10   21    
       1          11   27    
       2          12   8
       1          11   34    
       2          12   20
   110      -7      5.000              60
       1          10   30    
       2          10   21
```

If file `location` runs out of records, script prints empty records. See comments for related discussion.

Comment: This is ridiculously fast and efficient, thank you!

Comment: 25 more points then I have 25k and I can retire. 25k was the maximum amount of points that unlocked some features, right? This was the nicest game ever. Well, TF2 is a blast, too! Best rodeo ever. :D

Comment: Just be aware of the getline issues, especially if you're not going to test for it succeeding before using it's output - see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline. You can improve efficiency by testing `NF` instead of `$0==""` btw.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the tip on `NF`. On the `getline` issue: does any particular problem cross your mind in this application? I'd assume `$0` getting set to `""` in case of a read error and `if((getline < file) <= 0){print "";next}` not being any safer?

Comment: The most obvious issues would be location.txt not having as many lines as there are blank lines in time.txt or location.txt becoming unreadable while awk is executing. When getline fails $0 will just remain whatever it was before getline got called (so yes, `""` in  this case) and the way to protect against it would be more like `if ( (getline < file) <=0 ) print "the sky is falling" | "cat>&2"` or similar so the user gets a warning about it. The non-getline version I posted doesn't bother to report if there aren't enough lines in location.txt either - left as an exercise :-)

Comment: The current example isn't good for demonstrating this since it's calling getline for a blank input line and printing a blank line on a getline failure but one common problem with using getline this way occurs when you try to update an input file with the command output but one of the input files, say file1, can't be opened. If you use `awk 'script' file1 file2 > tmp && mv tmp file2` then the failure to open `file1` means that we won't overwrite the other input file, `file2`. If instead we used `awk '...getline < file...' file2 > tmp && mv tmp file2` unprotected then `file2` WILL be overwritten

Comment: Right and that's because of the specific nature of this question where we're not modifying any of the input data and your solution where on a getline failure we use $0 as it originally was and so we reproduce the input file as-is in the output when getline fails. Try something where we have to use the getline output to modify other input values though, e.g. create 2 files of numbers, make file1 unreadable, and then run `awk -v file='file1' '{old=$0; getline < file; print $0 / old}' file2` to try to divide the file1 values by the file2 values from the same line numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you are okay with `GNU sed`, you can use

```
sed -e '/^$/{R '"$location" -e 'd}' "$time"
```

- `/^$/` matches empty line from `$time` file
- `R` command allows you to read one line at a time from given file, `$location` in this case
- `d` command then deletes the empty line
- if empty line matches but no more lines to read, then the empty line gets deleted

Use `sed -i` if you wish to modify `$time` file in-place

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `location.txt` isn't so massive that it can't fit in memory:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{loc[NR]=$0; next} {print (NF ? $0 : loc[++c])}' location.txt time.txt
   110      -7      5.000              66
       1          5   20
       2          5   12
       1          6   3
       2          6   4
   110      -7      5.000              99
       1          10   30
       2          10   21
       1          11   27
       2          12   8
       1          11   34
       2          12   20
   110      -7      5.000              60
       1          10   30
       2          10   21
```